Is there an H^1 conforming interpolation with boundary condition with estimate?
Recently I have been researching Finite element analysis and I need an interpolation that satisfies (interpolation space $X_h\subset P^k$)

boundary interpolation $(u,v_h)_{\partial\Omega}=(\Pi u,v_h)_{\partial\Omega}$ for all $v_h\in X_h$

optimal estimate:$||\Pi u||_{H^1(\Omega)}\leq C||v||_{H^1(\Omega)}$


I found that the global Lagrange interpolation satisfies condition 1. and the least square interpolation satisfies 2. But I cannot combine them.
Is there any good idea or existed results?
